# Can a Carmichael number be even?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

Can a Carmichael number be even?

I know that a Carmichael number is a positive composite integer $n$ such that $a^n\equiv a \pmod n$ for all integer $a$. So what does I need to prove or disprove above question?

Comment: if n is even then $(n-1)^{n-1} = (-1)^{n-1} = -1$ (mod n) so n can't be a Carmichael number.

Comment: Note that this is not a "soft question." It has a clear answer: yes, it can or no, it cannot.

Comment: The same example, using $(n-1)^n$, will do the job with your not standard definition of Carmichael number.

Comment: @Soke, thanks, my bad

Answer (score 3):

No.
If $n\geq 4$ is even, then $(n-1)^{n-1} \equiv (-1)^{n-1} \equiv -1 \pmod n$